# How to extract endpoint from url , with Dart

Tags: string, flutter, parsing, dart, endpoint

My app scan QR code to get url like that :
http://website/api/123-5678-34234

I am looking for elegant solution to extract endpoint(123-5678-34234) without iterating through the whole url characters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
final a = Uri.parse('http://website/api/123-5678-34234');
print(a.path);
```

The output will be the path of your url:

```
/api/123-5678-34234
```

**EDIT**
Since you need just the last part of the path you can take advantage of the `pathSegments` `Uri`'s property:

In this case `a.pathSegments` will result in

```
["api", "123-5678-34234"]
```

So you could just pick `a.pathSegments.last`. I'm using last but it's an array so you can access it really like you want. Picking last will return the rightmost segment (the last one)

Comment: I just need (123-5678-34234)

Comment: Sorry! I've updated the answer in order to get what you need. It should be okay now